# "Nearest-Wins" dependency resolution and backwards compatibility

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-4.6

When referring to [this ASP.NET github wiki page](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Dependency-Resolution), it explains how packages of the same name (but different version) can be discarded using the "Nearest Win" scenario:

> Nearest wins means that the dependency resolver prefers versions that
>   are "closer" to the application, but only if they are an ancestor of
>   the dependency being rejected.

The example given explains how in the figure below, `Package B 1.0` will be discarded because `Package B 2.0` is "closer":

[image: Nearest-Wins dependency resolution]

**Does this mean that `Package A` will now use `Package B 2.0`?  Surely this doesn't make sense unless `Package B 2.0` is backwards compatible with `Package B 1.0`?**

Accordingly to [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) the above packages aren't necessarily backwards compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that MyApp will use PackageB 2.0, it also means that packageA in the context of MyApp will use PackageB 2.0. Note that in a package graph there is always only a single version of any individual package, this was true for the package.config world, and there is no change here. In the packages.config world that decision was made at package install time by the user, where here the decision is made at restore time.

Since it is always the user or the author of MyApp that authors the dependency graph either in project.json or in the nuspec (if MyApp was a package as well), he has the power to pick what version to use.

You are right that in this case there is a potential breaking change according to the semantic versioning rules. In this sample the author decided that it is not going to impact it's application or in your words that it is backward compatible enough for his use.

Another important aspect to keep in mind that the rule applies because the author MyApp has the power to make the change, not because Package B2.0 is arbitrarily closer to the root in the graph. Look at the cousin dependency rule, to understand this edge case.

Last the doc the question references is not the official guidance - it can be found here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution

Comment: Did you mean to write, "it also means that packageA in the context of MyApp will use PackageB *2.0*"?